# Trying to use a try_files rule with a redirect and pattern matching

Tags: nginx

I'm not sure how to use `try_files` with a redirect and pattern matching.

I have 2 blogs that are on `mysite.com/old_blog` and `mysite.com/new_blog`. I am writing nginx rules to redirect traffic from the `old_blog` to the `new_blog`. This following rule works for me:

```
location /old_blog {
    rewrite ^/old_blog(.*)$      /new_blog$1    permanent;
}
```

I am now trying to redirect a specific type of posts. On the old_blog, the urls are `/old_blog/post-name` (same as regular ones), but on the new_blog it will be `/new_blog/other/post-name`. What I want is: "redirect from `/old_blog` to `/new_blog`, if it's a 404, try to redirect to `/new_blog/other/`, if still nothing, then it's a legit 404".

I tried to use `try_files`, unsuccessfully:

```
location /old_blog(.*)$ {
    try_files /new_blog$1    /new_blog/other$1     =404;
}
```

Thanks for the help.